# Applying transformations on Dataset Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm handling a `Dataset<Row>`in Apache Spark using Java and need to do a couple of math transformations over all columns in this Dataset. Basically one of the transformations is to get the log of all values stored in this Dataset and still returning `Dataset<Row>`. I see clearly how to do that in a `map` function in a RDD, but how can I do that in a `Dataset<Row>`?

Context: `Dataset<Row> old` contains 2 columns `a` and `b`. I want to return a new `Dataset<Row> new` with both columns `a = log(a)` and `b = log(b)`

Comment: Please explain in more details what you are trying to do, what you did so far etc. Dataset has many functions which can be used.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is you can create a method that takes value of type a[column] and b[column] as parameter and return the log value.

suppose column a and column b are of type long

```
public long getLog(long value){ 
// yourlogic to generate log
}
```

then apply map function over dataset. Under map function you will get value as type `Row` the apply `getLong/getAs()` method to get corresponding value then pass this value to your custom log compute method i.e. `getLog` in our case then return resulting value .

you might need to return `Tuple2` for both value a and b column

Or you can create `udf` user define function of spqrk sql then apply `withcoumn` method to apply `udf`

**NOTE** udf will take value of type a [column] and b [column] as argument and return the log value .

Hope this work fine